# 'ZipArchiveEntry' does not contain the definition of 'ExtractToFile'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.NET Framework 4.7.1, I am trying to compress a file but Visual Studio is showing that `ZipArchiveEntry` does not contain the definition of `ExtractToFile`.

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file == null) 
        return View();

    string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads");

    using(ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(file.InputStream))
    {
        foreach(ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetExtension(entry.FullName)))
            {
                entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(path, entry.FullName));
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, entry.FullName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.extracttofile?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Is this shown as error on compilation or just in the editor?

Comment: do you have System.IO.Compression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although most of the `ZipArchive` functionality can be added by including a reference to `System.IO.Compression`, to use the `ExtractToFile` option you also need a reference to `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

It's not required to add it as a `Using` statement, just the reference is enough.

Comment: Core doesn't need this, but Framework does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The extension methods `CreateEntryFromFile()`, `ExtractToDirectory()` and `ExtractToFile()` can be accessed after installing the package `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` by using the following command:

**`Install-Package System.IO.Compression.ZipFile -Version 4.3.0`**